Android flutter app - Fatal Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: Internal error in Cloud Firestore (25.1.0)
I have introduced Firestore in my Android app to store user feedback messages:
Future<String> storeFeedbackInCloud(String feedbackText, String appVersion) async {
  try {
    String customDocumentID = 'feedback_${DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch}';
    final collection = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('feedback');
    await collection.doc(customDocumentID).set({
      'timestamp': FieldValue.serverTimestamp(),
      'feedback': feedbackText,
      'app_version': appVersion,
    });
    debugPrint('Feedback stored in FireBaseFirestore');
    return 'Feedback sent successfully';
  } catch (e) {
    debugPrint('Error when storing feedback in FireBaseFirestore');
    generateGALogEvent(name: "Ex_Cloud_Feedback", parameters: {});
    return 'Error when sending feedback';
  }
}

In testing, everything runs smoothly, feedback gets recorded as expected. All Firebase packages are up to date.
However, everytime when releasing the app to the play store, I observe the following crash in Crashlytics (potentially from the automatic Google Play Store tests), from a OnePlus8Pro on Android 11. What might be the reason for this?
      Fatal Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: Internal error in Cloud Firestore (25.1.0).
   at com.google.firebase.firestore.util.AsyncQueue.lambda$panic$3(AsyncQueue.java:19)
   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7680)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Method.java)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:423)
   at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)

More details:
Caused by l2.h: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean java.lang.String.isEmpty()' on a null object reference
       at com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzw.getResult(zzw.java:19)
       at com.google.firebase.firestore.remote.FirestoreChannel.lambda$runBidiStreamingRpc$0(FirestoreChannel.java)
       at com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzi.run(zzi.java:21)
       at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:462)
       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
       at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:301)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
       at com.google.firebase.firestore.util.AsyncQueue$SynchronizedShutdownAwareExecutor$DelayedStartFactory.run(AsyncQueue.java:15)
       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:923)

More details:
Caused by java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean java.lang.String.isEmpty()' on a null object reference
       at android.app.LoadedApk.createOrUpdateClassLoaderLocked(LoadedApk.java:830)
       at android.app.LoadedApk.access$100(LoadedApk.java:104)
       at android.app.LoadedApk$SplitDependencyLoaderImpl.constructSplit(LoadedApk.java:605)
       at android.content.pm.split.SplitDependencyLoader.loadDependenciesForSplit(SplitDependencyLoader.java:70)
       at android.app.LoadedApk$SplitDependencyLoaderImpl.ensureSplitLoaded(LoadedApk.java:640)
       at android.app.LoadedApk$SplitDependencyLoaderImpl.getSplitPathsForSplit(LoadedApk.java:649)
       at android.app.LoadedApk.getSplitPaths(LoadedApk.java:666)
       at android.app.ContextImpl.createResources(ContextImpl.java:2252)
       at android.app.ContextImpl.createPackageContextAsUser(ContextImpl.java:2315)
       at android.app.ContextImpl.createPackageContext(ContextImpl.java:2294)
       at android.content.ContextWrapper.createPackageContext(ContextWrapper.java:927)
       at com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtilLight.getRemoteContext(GooglePlayServicesUtilLight.java:3)
       at com.google.android.gms.security.ProviderInstaller.installIfNeeded(ProviderInstaller.java:68)
       at com.google.firebase.firestore.remote.GrpcCallProvider.initChannel(GrpcCallProvider.java)
       at com.google.firebase.firestore.remote.GrpcCallProvider.lambda$initChannelTask$6(GrpcCallProvider.java:4)
       at com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzz.run(zzz.java:4)
       at com.google.firebase.firestore.util.ThrottledForwardingExecutor.lambda$execute$0(ThrottledForwardingExecutor.java)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:923)

This is my build.gradle:
plugins {
    id "com.android.application"
    id "kotlin-android"
    id "dev.flutter.flutter-gradle-plugin"
    id "com.google.gms.google-services"
    id "com.google.firebase.crashlytics"
}

def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '2'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '0.2.5'
}

def keystoreProperties = new Properties()
def keystorePropertiesFile = rootProject.file('key.properties')
if (keystorePropertiesFile.exists()) {
    keystoreProperties.load(new FileInputStream(keystorePropertiesFile))
} 

android {
    namespace "com.cbt.chess_blunder_trainer"
    compileSdkVersion 34
    ndkVersion flutter.ndkVersion

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.XXX"
        // You can update the following values to match your application needs.
        // For more information, see: https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/android#reviewing-the-gradle-build-configuration.
        minSdkVersion 29 
        targetSdkVersion 34
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
        multiDexEnabled true
    }

   signingConfigs {
       release {
           keyAlias keystoreProperties['keyAlias']
           keyPassword keystoreProperties['keyPassword']
           storeFile keystoreProperties['storeFile'] ? file(keystoreProperties['storeFile']) : null
           storePassword keystoreProperties['storePassword']
       }
   }
   buildTypes {
       release {
           signingConfig signingConfigs.release
       }
   }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {
    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:33.2.0')
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics'
}

